# Built C app works inside folder it was built into, fails when brought outside of it

Tags: c, gtk, building

I'm making an app in C and I've built it using the following command:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` main.c -o hello `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lX11 -rdynamic
```

And this works, cool!
Except.. when I try to copy the exported file into another folder such as /usr/bin, then it throws the following errors:

```
(hello:11178): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:35:55.999: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(hello:11178): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:35:55.999: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(hello:11178): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 16:35:55.999: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Here's my code.
Ignore the meson file.
https://github.com/JohnyTheCarrot/Paperplane

pkg-config:

````
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include```
````

Comment: Can you show us the what `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` outputs?

Comment: I sure can! Added it to the post at the bottom. Cheers for replying!

Comment: How about if you copy the executable into another directory from home, such as ~/local/bin ? I suspect it might be a privilege issue.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find that directory so I created it. I seem to still get the same error.

Comment: What I'd do is sprinkle the `option_open` and `main` functions with printfs and see what `homedir` is set to.

Comment: If you get no answer, I'll try building the app tonight and see if I get the same errors.

Comment: When it's working or when it isn't? When it is working, that returns /home/johnythecarrot.

Comment: So when it's not working, you don't even get there? I assume you have `fflush(stdout)` in place.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the code does run, but it doesn't show the application window. I do not even know what fflush(stdout) is, sadly.

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` simply makes sure the `printf`s are printed before continuing.

Comment: Oh, I do a \n and that seems to print them.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the code, but I see you're opening your Glade-generated files using a relative path. All your calls to `gtk_builder_add_from_file` look like:

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "main_window.glade", NULL);
```

If you move only your binary, it won't be able to find these files anymore. One way to avoid that is to [reference the path in your meson file so you can use it in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473646/meson-working-with-data-assets-and-portable-relative-paths).

Also, you need to do some proper error checking. Where a `GError **error` is requested, use it and check for errors instead of passing NULL, and print the message return by the GError, it will save you lots of time.

```
guint
gtk_builder_add_from_file (GtkBuilder *builder,
                           const gchar *filename,
                           GError **error);
```

For more information, please read how [GError](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html) works (see "Description" section).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I seem to be getting the following error in meson: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Of course. You're supposed to declare your dependencies, then use them in `executable`, not the reverse. An executable has dependencies, which makes sense. I also don't get why you're calling pkg-config in the add_project_arguments, that makes no sense. Meson is already aware of pkg-config and knows how to call it. Please read the [basic GTK+ app with Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/Tutorial.html#adding-dependencies) example on the Meson website.

Comment: Thanks! I acknowledge that I am an idiot but I don't understand how to reference the path in my meson file with the link you've given me. Sorry.

Comment: You should stop loading by file and load by GResource: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html - https://mesonbuild.com/Gnome-module.html#gnomecompile_resources

Comment: The GResource suggestion worked, and my issue is resolved. Cheers, everyone!

Comment: @JohnyTheCarrot: sorry, didn't want to sound harsh. You need to first declare your dependency (something like `gtk_dep = dependency('gtk+-3.0')`), an **then** you can pass that `gtk_dep` variable to your `executable(...)` call. This way you give to the executable the list of its dependencies, otherwise it won't find them. Currently your code only does `executable('build_test', 'main.c')` and overlooks the `dependencies` parameter of `executable(...)`. Look at the basic example I linked above. It calls `executable('demo', 'main.c', dependencies : gtkdep)`, providing the deps to the executable.

Comment: Oh don't you worry about it, you weren't harsh! :)